# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2dt \int_{nx}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}}{1+n^3x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am preparing for the exam. Please help me to solve the following problem:

Given a series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2dt \int_{nx}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}}{1+n^3x^2}$$

determine, if it is uniformly convergent on 1) $(0, \infty)$ ? 2) $(0, c)$, where $c < \infty$ ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's single out the term at $n=0$ which is finite for all real numbers $x$.

Assuming we are asked to choose between the two answers where either 1) or 2) is true, then we may observe that
$$
\left|\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2dt\right|\leq 2,\quad \qquad n \in \{1,2,\cdots\},\,x \in \mathbb{R},
$$ and that
$$
\left|\int_{nx}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}\right|< \left|\int_{nx}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4}}\right|=\frac1{nx},\quad \qquad n \in \{1,2,\cdots\},\,x \in (0,\infty),
$$ giving, for any real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha>0$,
$$
\sup_{x\in [\alpha, \infty)}\left| \dfrac{\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2dt \int_{nx}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}}{1+n^3x^2}\right|\leq \frac2{n\alpha(1+n^3\alpha^2)},
$$ the latter related series being convergent$\displaystyle \left(<\frac1{\alpha^3}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^4}\right)$, then we select answer $1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you please update the solution to clarify last step? I will be happy to accept it after that. From what I understand in order to use Weierstrass M-test we must show that $\sup|a_n(x)|$ doest not depend on $x$, but it is not the case in your solution.

Comment: @Hedgehog You are welcome! We have proved that, for any $\alpha>0$, we have $\sup |u_n(x)|\leq v_n$, for all $x \in [\alpha,\infty)$ with $v_n$ independent from $x$ and $\sum v_n$ convergent, thus the initial series is uniformly convergent over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, cool, now I see independence from $x$. Stupid me :( What is the most elegant/shortest argument to show that last series converges?

Comment: That last series is $\displaystyle \leq \frac1{\alpha^3}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^4}$, which is $p$-series convergent $(p>1$). Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot and happy holidays!

Comment: The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n\alpha(1+n^3\alpha^2)}$ does not converge uniformly for $\alpha\gt0$. How does this show that the original series converges uniformly for $x\gt0$?

Comment: @robjohn Please, I'm not sure to understand your point. Could you tell me If you agree with the fact that, for each $\alpha>0$, I've proved the initial series is uniform over $[\alpha,\infty)$. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you've shown that the initial series converges uniformly over $[\alpha,\infty)$, but that does not show uniform convergence over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: OK, to my opinion we had to pick up the best answer where *at least one of the two answers is correct* (in french we call it a 'QCM'), that's why I wrote "we are inclined to...".

Comment: Certainly, if 2) is true, then this answer shows that 1) is true. However, unless I am misreading the question, the question does not assure that either is true.

Comment: Probably it is me who misread it :)

Comment: @Hedgehog I've edited my answer so you can accept robjohn's complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}
&=\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-3/4}\,\mathrm{d}t}{(t+1)^{1/2}}\\
&=\frac14\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}\\
&\le\int_0^1\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}\\[9pt]
&=1+1=2
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}
&\le\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}\\
&=\frac1{nx}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, using the harmonic mean of the bounds,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}\le\frac4{1+2nx}}
$$
Since
$$
\left|\sin((n+1)x)-\sin(nx)\right|\le2
$$
and
$$
\left|\sin((n+1)x)-\sin(nx)\right|\le(n+1)x-nx=x
$$
using the harmonic mean of the bounds, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{\sin(nx)}^{\sin((n+1)x)}\sin\left(t^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\le\frac{4x}{2+x}}
$$
Thus, when $x\le2$, the sum is less than
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{16x}{(1+2nx)(2+x)(1+n^3x^2)}
&\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{8x}{\left(1+2nx\right)\left(1+n^3x^2\right)}\\
&\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{8x}{\left(1+2nx\right)\left(1+Nn^2x^2\right)}\\
&\le\int_0^\infty\frac{8\mathrm{d}t}{\left(1+2t\right)\left(1+Nt^2\right)}\\
&\le\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{align}
$$
When $x\gt2$, the sum is less than
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{16x}{(1+2nx)(2+x)(1+n^3x^2)}
&\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{16}{\left(1+4n\right)\left(1+4n^3\right)}\\
&\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^4}\\
&\le\frac1{3(N-1)^3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the convergence is uniform over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: A solid answer :) (+1)