# Express $\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2dt$ in terms of $x$ and $n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

Please help me to express $$\int_{\sin nx}^{\sin(n+1)x}\sin t^2\,dt$$ in terms of $x$ and $n$. If it is not possible please help to establish bounds on the integral again in terms of $x$ and $n$. The reason for question is another (more complex) question involving uniform convergence of a series I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591313/uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-0-infty-frac-int-sin-nx-sinn1x-si).

Answer (score 0):

By substitution $t^2=\frac12\pi u^2$ we get

$$\int \sin(t^2)\,dt=\sqrt\frac\pi2\int\sin\left(\frac12\pi u^2\right)\,du=\sqrt\frac\pi2 S(u) = \sqrt\frac\pi2 S\left(\sqrt\frac\pi2 t\right)$$

So

$$\int_{\sin(nx)}^{\sin((n+1)x)} \sin(t^2)\,dt=
\sqrt\frac\pi2 S\left(\sqrt\frac\pi2 \sin((n+1)x)\right)-
\sqrt\frac\pi2 S\left(\sqrt\frac\pi2 \sin(nx)\right)$$

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply, but it is useless.